# Is it possible to access technical logs/Event Viewer on a Lumia WinPhone?

Tags: 8.1, lumia

I'm currently arguing a case where an authority claims that my sons phone was turned off at a specific point in time.

I have technical logs, serverside, that corroborate that his phone was active just around the time in question (5 minutes before and 4 minutes after the event), but I expect that with that they will then claim that his phone was just rebooting at the time.

Is it possible that I can obtain any kind of technical information from the phone, similar to Desktop Windows' Event Viewer, where vital system events can be seen? I've searched, but found no indication that it is possible, which is why I'm trying here.

(I've also contacted the phone company to see if I can get access to their logs as to whether the phone used their service at the given time.)

Answer (score 1):

As this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055515/how-to-collect-application-logs-in-windows-phone-8-1) suggests, Microsoft has introduced new APIs in 2013 that allow the developer to collect application logs and save them locally on the phone. So, if you are a developer you can use these APIs to get logging info from the app or the system. Also, read [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/A-logging-solution-for-c407d880) link which is solution written in C# for logging runtime application behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was not for applications developed by myself, more whether functionality to get an overall systems log similar to the Event Viewer that is available on desktop and server versions of Windows.